# How to set focus on tab in tabcontrol in URL

Tags: html, asp.net, exact-synergy-enterprise

I am trying to call a page in my customers webapplication (Exact Synergy Enterprise)

This is the link: `http://someserveridontdisclose/Synergy/docs/CSCANEduCourseCard.aspx?ProjectNr=ACPGINTV`

Within this page is an Ajax TabContainer with several TabPanels. One of them is called 'Doelgroepen'

I dont have the source for this application, as i am not the developer of it. We only develop custom extentions to it.

Here's the question: Is it possible to focus on one of the tabs USING ONLY AN URL? If so How?

Thank you very much for your thoughts about this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible just using url. But perhaps it would be possible. The question is - are you placing the url to some iframe ?If so, some JavaScript to handle this would be easy to implement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set with javascript. you'll have to write your own js to get index number you want from url, then set like this

```
$find('<%=TabContainer1.ClientID%>').set_activeTabIndex(2);
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1127834.aspx

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/420684/ASPNet-AJAX-TabContainer-Set-Active-Tab-Client-side-using-JavaScript/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to the code and if this is not part of the requirement / design specification for the application you are using (ie: what you asked the developer to do), then the answer is No.

The control does not have "native" support for URL tab selection. **There needs to be specific code in the application in order to handle this**.

It is however very easy to implement, if you absolutely need it, it shouldn't take much time (about 15-30 lines of code, depending on how many tabs/urls combination you need).

You can find a running sample of the AjaxControlToolkit Tabs control at the following link (the available functionnalities are described in there):
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the TAB has an ID you could make it visible by adding '#tabid' to the URL.